# How to iterate through the String value store in column Attributes with type longtext in MySql /nvarchar(max) in MS SQL

Tags: java

There is a columns attribute in MySQL (type - longtext) /MS SQL (type - nvarchar(max). It stored below value. I am getting the values through resultset in java like below.

```
while (rs.next()) {
```

String attributes = rs.getString("attributes");
}

```
The value returns below String value. Now I want to iterate through below. Can someone help here to get each      entry based on key and value.
```

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="contact_number" value="9990888"/>
    <entry key="displayName" value="Mohan Kumar"/>
    <entry key="email" value="mohan.kumar@testmail.com"/>
    <entry key="employee_address" value="Old Delhi"/>
    <entry key="employee_id" value="E00012"/>
    <entry key="employee_position" value="IT Manager"/>
    <entry key="employee_status" value="T"/>
    <entry key="employee_type" value="Permanent"/>
    <entry key="firstname" value="Mohan"/>
    <entry key="full_name" value="Mohan Kumar"/>
    <entry key="gender" value="Male"/>
    <entry key="job_code" value="UP-1001"/>
    <entry key="job_description" value="UP-IT Manager"/>
    <entry key="lastname" value="Kumar"/>
    <entry key="martial_status" value="Single"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to use an XML binding tech to get an `Employee` object. Btw you have a typo. It's *marital*, not "martial"

Answer (score 0):

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("key=\"(.*)\" value=\"(.*)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<Attributes>\n" +
            "  <Map>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"contact_number\" value=\"9990888\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"displayName\" value=\"Mohan Kumar\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"email\" value=\"mohan.kumar@testmail.com\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"employee_address\" value=\"Old Delhi\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"employee_id\" value=\"E00012\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"employee_position\" value=\"IT Manager\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"employee_status\" value=\"T\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"employee_type\" value=\"Permanent\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"firstname\" value=\"Mohan\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"full_name\" value=\"Mohan Kumar\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"gender\" value=\"Male\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"job_code\" value=\"UP-1001\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"job_description\" value=\"UP-IT Manager\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"lastname\" value=\"Kumar\"/>\n" +
            "    <entry key=\"martial_status\" value=\"Single\"/>\n" +
            "  </Map>\n" +
            "</Attributes>");
    var map = matcher.results().map(matchResult -> Map.entry(matchResult.group(1), matchResult.group(2)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

    System.out.println(map);
```

notice [results](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) method of the matcher exist since jdk 9 so it will not be there for jdk 8 if that what you are using

and here some tutorial for [regex](https://dev.java/learn/regex/) and [stream](https://dev.java/learn/the-stream-api/)

Comment: Thanks for the above solution but I am getting the value in one of String variable and it is not fixed for each result set. It is in the same format with less or more number of entry keys based on the values of key available or not.  So can you please provide your inputs in that way using String var where I get the value from result set in each iteration. I am also looking in the same.

Comment: you welcome @PramodKumarSingh do you mean that sometime there more entry and othertime less entry if yes then this fine for the above solution 
do you mean that sometime key exist but it does not has value? so how the entry look like in that case you can use filter of the stream but i need to see an example 
could you update your question with the new requirement provide more example would make it easier to get what you want to achive

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! I am getting the value in String attributes =  rs.getString("attributes"); so here the value is in variable attributes which you have
explained above. But there may be different value for different iteration or you can say id in which some entry key will not be there in case value is not mandatory like contact_number entry key. So how I can achieve the same with value getting in String variables attributes. Please let me know in case of any more details required.

Comment: you welcome @PramodKumarSingh if i got you in case if the value is not there then the the whole entry will not be inside the atterbuites am i right? so the above solution will not have the key for that entry as it not there or do you want that all keys should be there no matter if it inside the atterbuites or not and in case of that key not there what you want the value be null or something else please update your question with some example for that case